# How to copy certain range of files in Linux?

Tags: linux

I have a folder in which there are files range from `shg_receive_box_04_06_2019.xls` to `shg_receive_box_20_06_2019.xls`
how to copy only `04_06_2019.xls` to `15_06_2019.xls` in a single command?

Comment: What did you try ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```sh
for i in $(seq -f "%02g" 4 15); do cp shg_receive_box_${i}_06_2019.xls path/to/copy/to; done
```